# Installed new Motherboard, Windows failed to start

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Looked trough the Internet but couldn't find any solutions to this exact problem.

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 in Dual-boot and recently installed a new Motherboard, but when i try to Boot into windows, this message shows up:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.
Status: 0xc000000e
```

At least Ubuntu still works but without sound.

I have no clue what to do.

Comment: A problem with Windows caused by a change of hardware seems not to be an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: Wasn't sure if its just windows or grub or anything, i better post this again on some windows forum.

Comment: Post it on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 4):

This is totally off-topic on AskUbuntu, but here's an answer for you:

You can't just switch motherboards with Windows. It's just doesn't work. Linux can adapt to whatever hardware it's been booted on, but Windows cannot.

It's crashing because the drivers and such that you installed for your previous motherboard aren't compatible with your new one. Not to mention, switching your motherboard will deactivate your Windows license key as well...

Comment: So i should fresh install Windows?

Comment: @TGLG Yes, you should. You can backup your data from within Ubuntu

Comment: i just noticed i cant access the SSD from Ubuntu. It is listed as 256GB Volume but it wont open in the file explorer.

Comment: @TCLG - Well then please post that as a separate question...